# Integral involving Bessel and Laguerre function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, bessel-functions, laguerre

Is there a formulas for the following integral
$$\int^\infty_0 e^{-ar^2}L^1_k(b r^2)J_1(cr)r^d dr        $$
where $L^1_k$ is the Laguerre polynomials of type 1 and $J_1$ is the Bessel function with $a,b,c,d\geq 0$
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The Laguerre polynomial can be found in NIST Special functions: http://dlmf.nist.gov/18.5.E12 . And use 

$\int^\infty_0 e^{-ar^2}J_1(cr)r^\delta dr  =$ $\frac{1}{4} c a^{-1-\frac{\delta}{2}} \Gamma(1+\frac{\delta}{2}) _{1}F_{1}\left(1+\frac{\delta}{2},2,-\frac{c^{2}}{4\ a}\right)$. 
(Mathematica result) Could not find a reference for the integral, but maybe later.

So called Confluent Hypergeometric function $_{1}F_{1}$ is here https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/

Comment: Thnak you for your help. If we use your relations then the integral is equivalent to the sum $\sum^k_{j=0} \binom{k+1}{k-j}(-2)^j (j+1)_{1}F_{1}\left(j+2,2,-\frac{c^{2}}{4\ a}\right)$. Is there a closed formula for this

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you a lot

Comment: There IS in fact a simplification: for integer parameters the confluent hypergeometric function reduces of course considerably : $ _1F_1(n+m,n,z)=\exp(z) \sum_{j=0}^{m} {m \choose j } z^{j} / (n)_{j}$ (I have no link at hands for that formula, but should be online somewhere)

Comment: Thank you a lot@ Johannes Trost. I will use it.

Comment: I try to check your result for the integral that you stated in the comments. I can not reproduce it, yet. Are you sure, that it is correct ?

Comment: I m sure of it@ 
Johannes Trost

Comment: That would mean that the integral is independent of the exponent $d$ of $r$ under the integral.

Answer (score 2):

To wrap up here is the result for the OP's integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} dr \ e^{-a r^2}\ L_{k}^{1}(b \ r^2) \ J_{1}( c\ r)\ r^d = \\
\frac{(k+1)! \ c}{4 \ a^{\frac{d}{2}+1}}\sum_{n=0}^{k}\left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^n  \ \frac{\Gamma(n+\frac{d}{2}+1)}{(k-n)!\ n!\ (n+1)!} \ _{1}F_{1}\left(n+\frac{d}{2}+1,2;-\frac{c^2}{4\ a}   \right)
$$

Comment: Thank you a lot